# Using round() to get exact value - PHP

Tags: php

Hey guy's I am working on a project of mine which involves the use of money.  I am trying to not use round anymore because, it's rounding things to nearest tenth and I need exact numbers.  One reason I was using it, was because it was giving a whole number.

The way I am working my number system is that `100 = $1, 2000 = $20, etc..`  I was currently using the round function because it would get rid of the decimal point for me and give me a whole number, lets say: `223` which in turn would = `$2.23`.

Here is what I am using:

```
$amount += round(($amount / 29) + 30);
```

Here are the numbers:

Lets say we have a charge of `100 and we add 125 which equal 225 (USD $2.25)`.  Now we add taxes and processing: `+ 2.9% + $.30`.  After multiplying `2.25 by 2.9%` and adding `.30` the amount would be: `0.36525` - this is the amount that should be added than to the `$2.25 which than would be 261 = $2.61`

The issue is because of the rounding, when I look in my Stripe panel `(I am using Stripe API for payments)` I see a charge of `$2.63`.  So my question is, how would I go about making it exact without having any rounding and decimal places.

UPDATE:

Here is the above example more explained:

Lets say we have a charge of `100 and we add 125 which equal 225 (USD $2.25)`.  Now we add taxes and processing: `+ 2.9% + $.30`.  After multiplying `2.25 by 2.9%` and adding `.30` the amount would be: `0.36525` - this is the amount that should be added than to the `$2.25 which than would be 261 = $2.61`

So now with that the actual value of amount that should be charged is `$2.61` but instead when using the round it gives me `263` which also means `$2.63`.  The above example is the simple math that is correct.

Comment: I’m not sure I understand your question. Can you give an example where rounding is off, and what you’d expect the result to be instead?

Comment: Ya here check my update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to avoid calculation hiccups like that, only round the final result. Keep all other calculations as accurate as possible:

```
$original = 100;
$original += 125;

$tax = $original * 2.9 / 100; //+2.9%
$tax += 30; //+$.30

$original += $tax; //Add tax.

echo $original; //Result is 261.525. Round as you please.
```

Comment: So I can just take all that add to `$original` and use `round($original)`?

Comment: @DavidBiga: Basically, yes. Round the final result, and not the intermediate stages. You lose accuracy if you do so.

Comment: Hey so I did what you said and added the `$original = round($original);` but it rounds to the 262 instead of staying at 261, is that okay?

Comment: @DavidBiga: Fact is, your required sum is closer to 2 than it is to 1. If you want to round it one way or another, look at `ceil()` or `floor()`.

Comment: I know that but what do you recommend?  Do you recommend letting it round up 1 cent if necessary?

Comment: @DavidBiga: If you don't want to take chances, round in favor of the customer.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify precision and rounding method to keep it consistent ([PHP round()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php)), then you can deal with the actual values. Doing math tricks like multiplication by a multiple of 10 will only make it more confusing in the long run.

```
$amount += round(($amount / 29) + 30, 2, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP);
```

Will this solve your problem?

Comment: I forgot the $ on the left-handed $amount when I copied/pasted. If it's still giving you problems, try round((($amount/29)+30), 2, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP)

Comment: @CurtisMattoon: You realize this is just getting more and more confusing, right?

Comment: @CurtisMattoon ya you are making it very confusing.  Thanks though.